# how to set the folder permission programatically in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to set the folder permission programatically.  My requirement is  when i set the parent folder, all its subfolders must inherit the parent permissions.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use the System.Management and System.Security frameworks:

http://www.redmondpie.com/applying-permissions-on-any-windows-folder-using-c/

To apply the same permissions in all subdirectories, you would need to use a foreach loop to iterate over all subdirectories of the directory you wish to modify.

Comment: System.Management is only used in the article to get a list of users. For the subdirectories, surely better off correctly setting the InheritanceFlags and PropogationFlags in the ACLs so they inherit the permissions from the parent..