# Deny inheritance to a folder?

Tags: c#, ntfs

How to remove inherited permissions from a folder programatically, the permissions that were inherited from the parent folder..

or else

uncheck checkbox "inherit from parent the permission entires that apply to child objects......etc" from advanced security tab..?

Comment: So, what have you tried yourself? =)

Comment: To be fair, googling problems like this usually directs you to stackoverflow, so there is a point with having questions like this. However, the quality of the question itself could be improved with, say, OPs own attempts.

Comment: To be fair google probably would have taken you here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163885.aspx or here http://www.redmondpie.com/applying-permissions-on-any-windows-folder-using-c/.  Both of which help.  There is also a stack question which is similar here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096393/how-to-set-the-folder-permission-programatically-in-c-sharp

Comment: I did say usually. Most people don't seem to look past the first or second result.

Comment: i have tried redmonpie, nd all the above but i did not get the desired result...im giving certian permissions to a parent folder with inheritance, that parent folder is having 2 child folders, 1 child should inherit the properties from parent and the other child should not get the parent properties